# How to redirect url with proxypass nginx

Tags: node.js, redirect, nginx, nginx-location, proxypass

I use nginx Nginx as web server, and project build use Nodejs. There are 2 Project, one run on port 6000 and another on port 7000.
Every request  api.mysite.com will redirect to project 1 (localhost:6000), and request  api.mysite.com/v2 will redirect to project 2 (localhost:7000).
But,I want request api.mysite.com/oauth/token redirect to localhost:7000/oauth/token

In the server block , I have configure like this

```
upstream mysiteapiv1 {
     server localhost:6000;
}
upstream mysiteapiv2{
     server localhost:7000;
}


server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.mysite.com;

  root /var/www/html/v1;
  location / {
     proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
     proxy_pass         http://mysiteapiv1;
  }

  location /v2 {
     proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
     proxy_pass         http://mysiteapiv2;
  }

  location /oauth/token {
    #  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    #  proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
       proxy_pass         http://localhost:7000/oauth/token;
  }


  location /public/ {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

But request api.mysite.com/oauth/ resulted not found
What should I do ?

Comment: You have a typo in `http://localhost:7000/oatuh/token;`. But the URI is not required, as `http://localhost:7000` should work just as well. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: thanks @RichardSmith,  http://localhost:7000 work as api.mysite.com/v2, 
but I want api.mysite.com/oauth/token will redirect to http://localhost:7000/oauth/token